# ConstantScoreRangeQuery is deprecated

Tags: lucene

I have just stepped into lucene world and trying to understand the use of ConstantScoreRange query and its alternative in lucene 6.2.1.

After googling I found that ConstantScoreRange is deprecated and I should go for either `NumericRangeQuery` or `TermRangeQuery` from this link: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/core/deprecated-list.html

I am currently using Lucene 6.2.1 library and trying to change this code snippet :

```
public Query toQuery() {
         return new ConstantScoreRangeQuery(getName(), lowValue, highValue, true, true);
}
```

in a format that is suitable in lucene 6.2.1

As per my understanding the requirement is to use `NumericRangeQuery` as the data being passed to `ConstantScoreRangeQuery` were numeric and not terms.

Since `NumericRangeQuery` API is also deprecated in Lucene 6.2.1 I am not sure which is the right API to be used.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 2):

As of 6.0, the old numeric types have been deprecated and renamed ([LegacyIntField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LegacyIntField.html), for instance), and should be replaced with [PointValues](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/PointValues.html), which offer overall better performance.

To use it for an integer value, for instance, you would index like this:

```java
int myIntValue = 10;
document.add(new IntPoint("myIntField", myIntValue));
```

And to query it:

```java
Query query = IntPoint.newRangeQuery("myIntField", 5, 15);
```